# Get long offset name for a timezone using moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

The luxon library adds this feature to get the `offsetNameLong` acc. to timezone ianaName which provides a locale specific translated zone name. For instance

```
DateTime.local().setLocale("en-US").setZone("America/Los_Angeles").offsetNameLong // prints Pacific Daylight Time
DateTime.local().setLocale("ja-JP").setZone("America/Los_Angeles").offsetNameLong // prints アメリカ太平洋夏時間
```

Because of `luxon` less IE browser support(unless using polyfills), I'd like to do something similar using `moment-timezone`. I'm just curious if `moment-timezone` provides a similar feature to do the same, or, any other alternative to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like moment.js doesn't support long names of timezones, however offers a custom way to use long names instead of abbreviations that `zoneAbbr()` returns.

**Reference**: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/

```js
var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/New_York').format('zz');    // Eastern Standard Time
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/New_York').format('zz');    // Eastern Daylight Time
moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // Pacific Standard Time
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // Pacific Daylight Time
```